# How Do I Create A Full Width Header That Remains Full Width Even If I Resize Browser Window?

Tags: html, css

lets say i created a div with an id of header like this
`<div id="header"></div>` and on the css i write

```
#header{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#00ff00;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;}
```

well this creates a full width header but when i re size the width of the browser and using the scroll bar i scroll right i find that the background doesn't reach the full width of the browser its the same thing with when i use a background image does anyone know a solution to this

Comment: Where is your code, and a minimal duplication of your issue? Without that we are unfortunately unable to help.

Comment: @OT whats the point in that as long as ive made the point then its okay

Comment: @Terry ive written the code its highlighted in grey on the description for the question

Comment: There is possibly something else on the page which is causing the issue. Not sure about it.

Comment: That code is insufficient to reproduce your problem — that's why on SO it is *always* helpful to have a working issue that we can take a look at. Judging from the issue you are facing there are probably other interfering elements and/or styles that are causing the issue.

Comment: Don't set the width, just leave it as `display:block` and it will fill all available width by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of off, if you're going to be using this truly as a header you should use the
`<header>` tag to keep your HTML semantic instead of the usual `<div>` approach.

Second, you may be seeing 100% width issues due to default formatting on `<html>` and the `<body>`

If you want to have a full width header, you'll need to do something like this:

```
html,body{ /* basic html, body reset */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px; /* easier to visualize with a larger header size */
    background: url('someimage.url');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

The background-cover css property is very useful to maintain aspect ratios especially if this is for a responsive site.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background: url(http://oi49.tinypic.com/9kpge0.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/6Lo75x2n/)